# The last over bowler one and two ball is slow and batsman mostly deceive. what is reasons?

Tags: cricket

the last five over bowler try to slow bouncer back-of hand. Batsman try to hitting the ball and maximum score on bod. but batsman deceive what is reasons`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becuase last 5 over game is the turning point.... If the batsman batting long period before that 5 over  then he seeing the ball like football size.. So no matter bowler bowl which ball batsman deceive that ball and connect well with tha bat

Answer (score 0):

Well it’s just because the batsman in the last overs tries to get on the ball and score, and not wait for the ball to come on the bat. When a batsman tries to hit six, he judges the pace to begin the swing of his bat and make contact with the ball at the perfect time. The batsman has played the against the pacer in earlier overs and knows how the pacer bowls.